# Is it possible to compile SDRPlusPlus on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, compiling, cmake

Currently new SDR related software named [SDRPlusPlus](https://github.com/AlexandreRouma/SDRPlusPlus) is available as [deb-packages](https://github.com/AlexandreRouma/SDRPlusPlus/releases/tag/1.0.3) only for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer versions.

Is it possible to compile SDRPlusPlus on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if one follows recommendations from GitHub [issue](https://github.com/AlexandreRouma/SDRPlusPlus/issues/263).

Programmatically it will be possible by using the following commands:

```
# add PPA withe newer CMake
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt-get update

# install dependencies
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libfftw3-dev libglfw3-dev libglew-dev libvolk1-dev libsoapysdr-dev libairspyhf-dev libiio-dev libad9361-dev librtaudio-dev libhackrf-dev libairspy-dev librtlsdr-dev

# clone source, patch and compile
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/AlexandreRouma/SDRPlusPlus.git
cd SDRPlusPlus
git reset --hard b2ce47d

cmake  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-lstdc++fs" -D OPT_OVERRIDE_STD_FILESYSTEM=ON  -DOPT_BUILD_AIRSPYHF_SOURCE=OFF .
sed -i "s|^cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)|cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)\nadd_compile_options(-fpermissive)|" CMakeLists.txt core/CMakeLists.txt
make -j$(nproc)

sh make_debian_package.sh .
sudo apt-get install ./sdrpp_debian_amd64.deb
```

Then one can launch SDRPlusPlus by `sdrpp` command or using SDR++ icon in the menus.